# VSCode autocomplete for Django orm lookups/property not working

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, django-orm, django-model-field

How to autocomplete django orm property or lookups in VSCode?

Just like it works in Pycharm Professional Edition as follow:

[image]

Comment: not available as such natively.

Comment: Always makes me wondering why people want to use VSCode... Like any VS, it looks like "bloatware"...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it is quite lightweight in my experience.  Modular with extensions and very fast generally.